# SML Operator and operand don't agree in foldr

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm working on an assignment where I have to write a function to get the length of a list. This is a trivial task, but I've come across something that I don't understand.

My simple code

```
val len = foldr (fn(_, y) => y + 1) 0
```

produces this warning

> Warning: type vars not generalized because of
>      value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)

and when I try to run it in the REPL, I get this:

```
len [1, 2, 3, 4];
stdIn:18.1-18.17 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
operator domain: ?.X1 list   operand:     
[int ty] list   in expression:
    len (1 :: 2 :: 3 :: <exp> :: <exp>)
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I do know some functional programming principles, and this should work, since its very simple partial application.

Of course I can make it work without partial application, like this

```
fun len xs = foldr (fn(_, y) => y + 1) 0 xs
```

but I would like to understand why the first version doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an instance of the [value restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction) rule application:

> In short, the value restriction says that generalization can only occur if the right-hand side of an expression is syntactically a value.

Syntactically,

```
foldr (fn(_, y) => y + 1) 0
```

is *not* a value, it's a function application, that's why it hasn't been assigned a *polymorphic* type. It has been instantiated with a dummy type, which has a very limited use, e.g. this works:

```
len []
```

but in most cases `len` defined as `val` is useless.

This restriction exists to guarantee type safety in the presence of variable assignment (via references). More details can be found in the linked page.

Comment: I see, so it hasn't been assigned a type... But why doesn't it just infer the type from the `foldr` function? I would think that partial application would simply be a function *value* with the same types as `foldr`, just without its first two arguments.

Comment: Indeed, the term with two applications reduces to a function value, but the compiler only treats this *syntactically*. This means it *won't reduce* anything, it just looks at the shape of a term. Sometimes this rule is overcautious and rejects well-behaved programs, somewhat like many type systems reject something like `1 + (if 0 = 0 then 1 else true)`, which clearly doesn't do anything harmful. But it is a small price to pay for type safety. And it does not incur any run-time overhead, which is important as well.